# Large dataset processing for Tensorflow Federated

Tags: tensorflow-federated

What is the efficient way to prepare ImageNet (or other big datasets) for Tensorflow federated simulations? Particularly with applying custom map function on tf.Dataset object? I looked into the tutorials and docs but did not find anything helpful for this usecase. This tutorial (https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/custom_federated_algorithms_2) shows MNIST processing but this dataset is relatively small.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please clarify what exactly you mean by "efficient" in this context. I presume you've tried something, and it wasn't working as expected. Could you please describe here how you went about setting it up, and what problems you ran into. Thanks!

One thing to note is that the runtime included in the first release will only work with datasets that fit in memory. Perhaps this is the limitation you are running into.